# Symbolize layer and group names in TOC?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, symbology, table-of-contents

I regularly have quite large mxd projects, with lots of feature layers referenced in Table of Contents (TOC). For simplicity I group them together. The problem is that I can't see the difference between a feature layer or a group (or a group of groups).

It is not only me using these documents, and it would be really useful to be able to colorize the name of groups and/or feature layers or have any other way of separate them from each other (other than having to press the +).

At the very least I'd like to have one color for groups and another for feature layers, but being able to choose freely would be a big improvement. Then I can have blue for water related stuff, red for administrative, green for... you get the picture.

Is there any such functionality in Arcmap? Or has anyone made a neat add-in that could do this?

[image: TOC]

*Arcgis 10.1 on Windows 7*

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing native within arcgis that Im aware of, a custom add-in would be your best bet but I've not seen anything like it unfortunantly. If you have some funds to contribute to custom development let me know and I'll chat to a developer friend to see if we can come up with something, as you say it would be very handy.

Regards,
Rowan